# running a full node on a network restricted to outbound connections on port 80 via proxy

Tags: port, proxy, full-node, firewall

Wanted to know if there is any way i can run a full node on a machine in a restricted LAN that can not exit outbound packets except to a specific proxy on port 80 ?
(an answer requiring to use an additional special server to forward packets that sits on an open network can be considered too) can SOCKS help ?